# Need some suggestions on some CSS formatting issue with table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I'm working on a game and am using a table as a form in order for the player to fill out some information. I am using jQuery so that when the button is clicked after the number of players is input, a new text box appears for each name. The issue is I'd like these input fields to appear in rows below the number of players input box, but when I use the `.after` jQuery function they end up going straight to the top of my table. I was wondering what I could do to add to the table by creating rows right underneath the current ones, or if you  have any input on a method other than a table for an input form which I can manipulate, a lot? I've attached some of my code, for the functions that deal with `.after` and the table, your input is much appreciated! :)

```
<div class=form>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Gender:</td>
    <td><form>
        <input type="text" name="genderItem"/>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class ="button" id="button1">Add!</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Number of charcters:</td>  
    <td><form>
        <input type="text" name="charcItem"/>
        </form>
    </td>
    <td> <div class="button" id="button2">Add!</div> </td>
    </tr>
    <div id="holder"></div>
    </table>
```

```
$('#button2').click(function(){
names=$('input[name=charcItem]').val();
nameRecording(names);
});    
function nameRecording(names){
    for(var i =1; i<=names; i++)
        $('#holder').after('<tr><td>Name one:</td><td><form><input type="text" name="charcItem"/></form></td></tr>');

};
```

Comment: You can not add a `<div>` to a `table` that way. It needs to be in a `<td>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the div  with id 'holder' was causing the major problem.
I have refined your code and its working as you expected.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6xbcE/2/) is the jsfiddle for the same

**HTML CODE:**

```
<div class=form>
<table >
<tr>
<td>Gender:</td>
<td><form>
    <input type="text" name="genderItem"/>
    </form>
</td>
<td>
    <div class ="button" id="button1">Add!</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Number of charcters:</td>  
<td><form>
    <input type="text" name="charcItem"/>
    </form>
</td>
<td> <div class="button" id="button2">Add!</div> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

**JS CODE:**

```
  $('#button2').click(function () {
  names = $('input[name=charcItem]').val();
  removeRows();
  nameRecording(names, $(this));

});

function removeRows() {
  $('#newRows').remove();
}

function nameRecording(names, $this) {
  var addRows = '<tr id=newRows>';
  for (var i = 1; i <= names; i++) {
    var nearTr = $this.closest('tr');
    addRows = addRows + '<td>Name one:</td><td><form><input type="text" name="charcItem"/></form></td>';
  }
 addRows = addRows + '</tr>';
 nearTr.after(addRows);
 }
```

**EDIT:**

The above code and Fiddle has been updated appropriately to support dynamic row creation.

Comment: I think this assumes that the rows will go at the end of the table, but these rows need to be inserted in the middle of a table.

Comment: I have updated the fiddle, check if this is fine with you,http://jsfiddle.net/6xbcE/1/

Comment: Updated fiddle to reflect the row count changes dynamically,http://jsfiddle.net/6xbcE/2/

Comment: @bala: Your Welcome. one more thing please check the appropriate answer as the final answer, so that it will reduce the no of open questions from SO Open Questions Pool.

Comment: Hi @dreamweiver do you have any suggestions on reading the knew input fields I am creating into an array. like name[0],name[1], name[2] and so on...?

Comment: ok, you want to read the value of the newly created input text boxes is it ? thats easy, just add a class for the newly created input textboxes. like this `<input type="text" name="charcItem" class='newR'/>` then you can extract the values of each text field using jquery like this `$('.newR').each(function() { var txtValue=$(this).val();  //do whatever required with each text box value  } ) ` .

Comment: Wow I think this is exactly what I've been looking for! Will keep in touch, thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Placing a `DIV` element inside a `TABLE` element is a bad idea.
You should either put the `DIV` inside a `TD` or `TH` element.

Better yet, you should ignore the div entirely, and insert your rows after another row.

`$("#button2").parent().after('<tr><td>Name one:</td><td><form><input type="text" name="charcItem"/></form></td></tr>');`

Comment: Excellent, I actually had to call parent twice, but it works fine now, thank you!

Comment: Wouldnt that add the additional rows within the Tr under which the button is placed ? I guess the functionality will work this way as well,expect that it will not be under new  row, this will be a problem when reediting the now of players list,as it would require a complex selector to delete the existing rows, before applying the new set of rows.

Comment: In my answer, this would be easy, since you just need to add a id to the Tr which is getting added newly, so before added new set of rows, delete this tr entirely :) hope @bala is understanding this

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try

```
$('<tr><td>Name one:</td><td><form><input type="text" name="charcItem"/></form></td></tr>').insertAfter($('.form table tr:last');
```

Comment: Will this cause the row to be inserted after the last row? Because I will need to insert rows after rows which are not the last row

Answer (score 0):

Good old tables <3

It would be a lot easier to just do the markup with divs. Something like this:

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="form_container">
        <div class="text_field">
            Gender
        </div>
        <div class="input_field">
            <input type="text" name="genderItem" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_add_container">
        <input type="button" name="button" id="add_button1" value="Add" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This may require some more markup and styling, but it should be no problem to float the elements and wrap them in their containers.

Then the js-code could be something like this:

```
$('#add_button1').on('click',function () {
    $('.form_container').append('<div class="text_field">Gender</div><div class="input_field"><input type="text" name="genderItem" /></div>');
});
```